# Confused with selecting an accepted answer.

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278728/some-clever-trick-is-required-for-this-integral-with-irrational-power-of-cosine/) all answers are very good [exclude mine if you want, which I added later].

- One answer is very short and pretty to be accepted.
- One explicitly calculates the value.
- One does it without any high-level functions.
- The last one is mine which I made for the time being since I haven't accepted any and I need to wait 2 days for mine. This is something like the second.

I am confused and want help as to what should be done is such cases and what I should do?

Comment: I was writing an answer that was very similar to yours (I am very used to that particular integration by parts to reduce $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^\alpha(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$). I like that one. However, accept the one you think helped you the most or the one you liked best. I know it is 15 points, but in the end it is all up to your preference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's entirely up to you how you choose which answer to reward with a green checkmark; you don't have to explain or defend your reasoning to anyone.

But please do choose *something* if you consider your problem solved due to the answers. If everything else fails, throw dice.

In the great scheme of things, who gets the 15 meaningless internet points is not as important as the fact that the question does get into the "has accepted answer" state.

Answer (score 7):

It was asked 13 hours ago? What's the big hurry? Let's select the Republican candidate for 2016 first, then accept an answer for this question.

Seriously though, as of this moment, your question isn't even old enough to put a bounty on. I suggest you wait until you can put a bounty on it. Maybe by then the decision will be easier. If not, go ahead and put a bounty on it. Maybe "canonical answer required" or "improve details."

But there's no ticking bomb with a countdown that can only be stopped by accepting an answer. If you let too much time pass, you'll get a gentle nudge that says "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"

Comment: I actually got "Republican candidate for 2016" on my third read :D

Comment: Jeb Bush might actually be the sanest of the lot.

Comment: Of course by now my remark "your question isn't even old enough to put a bounty on" is seriously outdated.